# How to add extra option to WP core gallery block?

Tags: block-editor

I want to add the extra option to the "Link to" attribute of "core/gallery" WP block. As default, It has three options,
[image]

1. Attachment page
2. Medial file
3. None

I want to add extra option to the existing three and make them like

1. Attachment page
2. Medial file
3. None
4. Custom

Any help would be appreciated.